# Background color based on two data dates

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to color the background of the rows of the table in the report based on two dates. Here is the logic I am trying to get

- if Date A < (Date B + 7 days) then I want the row to be Green
- if Date A is greater than (Date B + 7 days) but less than (Date B + 14 days) then I want the row to be yellow
- If Date A is greater than (Date B + 14 days) then I want the row to be red.

Date A and Date B are both fields in my report.

Answer (score 0):

The SWITCH function will let you have multiple conditions with a results for each - like a CASE statement.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!DATE_A.Value <= DATEADD("d", 7, Fields!DATE_B.Value), "MintCream",
        Fields!DATE_A.Value >= DATEADD("d", 14, Fields!DATE_B.Value), "MistyRose",
        Fields!DATE_A.Value > DATEADD("d", 7, Fields!DATE_B.Value) AND Fields!DATE_A.Value < DATEADD("d", 14, Fields!DATE_B.Value), "Ivory",
        1 = 1, "LightGrey")
```

The first (and every other) argument is the expression to be evaluated, the second is the value if true.

A `1 = 1` can be added as an evaluated expression as an ELSE for the SWITCH.

I usually use paler shades for background highlighting.

Comment: this looks like it works. One thing I was thinking of adding was if Date A was null still and todays date is so many days after Date B it would be a certain color. What would that look like? so like IF Date_A is null and Today's date is > (Date_B+14) then the row turns red

Comment: @KyraSlemp - something like `ISNOTHING(Fields!DATE_A.Value) AND TODAY >= DATEADD("d", 14, Fields!DATE_B.Value), "MistyRose",` - TODAY gives the date and the ISNOTHING checks for NULL values in an SSRS expression so if date A is NULL and TODAY is 14 days past Date B then it'll be true.